# Trigonometric functions - $\cos$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given $$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \frac {\sqrt{2}}{2}$$ what is the value of $$\cos\left(\frac{ 3\pi}{4}\right)$$

This is confusing me a lot. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your problem comes from the restrictive definition with triangles cos=adjacent side/hypotenuse which makes you thing that a cosine is always a poisitive number. In this case, your lecturer must show you how to use the trigonometric (unit) circle !

Comment: @JeanMarie I finally got my program to accept my answer! I'm trying to insert my answer into the program im using for university but it just wasn't working so I didn't know if I had the correct answer or not. And I apologise if this question is way too simple/vague for this stack!

Comment: See the modification I have done to my answer. Don't worry, no question is "too simple": this is not the problem...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the fact that $\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos x$. This gives us that $$\cos \frac{3\pi}{4}=-\cos \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Would that make it -2^(1/2)/2

Comment: @user421546, Yes this would be it $\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Practice drawing the trig circle. I am really sorry I haven't figured out graphics on this system yet. Draw this according to instructions, label it, and memorize the definitions. It solves a huge number of trig questions on one look.

(1) Circle center origin O, radius = $r$. (Don't always limit yourself to the unit circle; the general form is so much more useful.) Equation $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$

(2) Point A where circle meets positive x-axis. A = $(r. 0)$

(3) Make a clock hand along vector OA. This is your *initial ray*.
Turn it *counterclockwise* until the end of the vector is at any point P on the circle. Draw some sketches with P in each of the four quadrants as well as on the axes. Label the coordinates of P = $(x,y)$. OP is the *terminal ray*.

(4) From P (in any position on the circle), draw a perpendicular to the x-axis. The height of the triangle you just made is $y$, its base is $x$, the angle between $x$ and $y$ is of course a right angle (cartesian plane) and the hypotenuse is $r$.

(5) Trace the path of the end of the clock hand as you turn it from OA to OP. This portion of the circle is known as the *arc$.

---

NOTE (learn and memorize) We always assume that $r$ is positive. By Pythagoras, $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

DEFINE (no depth here, nothing to do, this is just what these things *are*, what they mean.)

Angle $\theta$ in *standard position* = $\angle AOP$; positive angles measured as *counterclockwise* turns.

Angle $\theta$ = arc/$r$

$\sin \theta = y/r$

$\cos \theta = x/r$

$\tan \theta = y/x =$ SLOPE of OP = $\sin \theta / \cos \theta$

secondary ratios

$\sec \ theta = r/x = 1/ \cos \theta$

$\csc \theta = r/y = 1/ \sin \theta$

$\cot \theta = x/y = 1/ \tan \theta = \cos \theta / \sin \theta$

---

Look at angles. A full turn $360^\circ = 2 \pi r / r = 2\pi$

Half turn = $180^\circ = 1/2 (2 \pi) = \pi$

Right angle = $90^\circ = \pi/2$

$45^\circ = \pi/4$

$60^\circ =   \pi /3$

$30^\circ = \pi/6$

Other common angles are just multiples of these. No fancy formulas needed.

So draw your trig circle with angle $\pi/4 = 45^\circ$ and another one with angle $3 \pi/4 = 3 (45^\circ)$

You have two identical $45^\circ - 45^\circ - 90^\circ $ triangles, one on the right side of the y axis in the firt quadrant, one on the left in the second quadrant.

No fancy rules needed, just look: $\pi/4$ in first quadrant has sine $y$ positive, cosine $x$ positive and tangent (slope) positive. $3\pi/4$ in second quadrant has sine $y$ positive, cosine $x$ negative and tangent (slope) negative.  $|y| = |x| = \sqrt{1/2} = 1/\sqrt 2 = \sqrt2 / 2$

It takes many times longer to write this than it does to do it. Just look at your diagrams and it is clear tht $\cos \pi/4 = \sqrt2 / 2$ and $\cos 3\pi / 4 = - \sqrt 2 / 2.$

To make your trig much more comprehensible, faster and more accurate, memorize those simple definitions above and always do a quick sketch of the angle in your margins

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {3 \pi} {4}$ is in the second quadrant, to which $sin \ \theta$ is the dominant positive angle, hence $cos \ \theta$ is negative in that quadrant. Rewriting $cos \ \frac {3 \pi} {4}$ as -$cos \ \frac { \pi} {4}$ (coterminal angle) gives us -$\frac {\sqrt 2} {2}$, as needed.

Update: Thanks to Victoria's helpful note below, I have removed the ASTC mnenomic.

Comment: In my experience of forty years teaching, this kind of mnemonic looks cute and for the vast majority it fails miserably. Students kind of vaguely half remember it and mix it up with the other five thousand pieces of trivia and splinter skills they have been given. A logical and concrete definition tied logically to other things they have learned has way better retention and transfer.

Comment: I can't argue with that.  Some students get it, others will still return a blank stare (or try to fight you with "I can understand what you're saying, BUT") after you've explained it to them, Your explanation below is much neater and direct.